# Is cancelByProducingResumeData is only for server which supports byte range requests?

Tags: ios, http-headers, nsurlsession

I'm using NSURLSession to download epub file from server, which needs to support pause/resume downloads.

On referring Apple docs I found some conditions needs to be handled from server side for using  `cancelByProducingResumeData`

Out of the conditions in Apple docs below conditions are not handled in my server

1. The server provides either the ETag or Last-Modified header (or
   both) in its response
2. The server supports byte-range requests

Is there any workaround that can be done from client side for pause/resume with out making changes in the response headers? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At least for background downloads, there is no alternative to that server feature, but if you’re able to write CGI scripts or similar, it is easy enough to add those headers.  That said, I would be concerned about the security of any server that lacks such basic functionality in this day and age, as most major servers have supported it for a decade at this point—unless, of course, the reason for the lack of support is that you are using a CGI script that lacks this support, in which case the solution is to fix the script.

For foreground downloads, you can use chunking as a rather crude alternative.  Break the file up into shorter pieces and assemble them in your client code.  That way, you only have to refetch a single chunk if it fails or the user pauses the download.

That said, most EPUB files are small enough that I have to wonder if it is even worth the effort.  Most users are going to be on a fast LTE network while doing downloads, where an average EPUB will download in a fraction of a second.